# How do I maintain the comparison between two things in this sentence without it sounding redundant?

Tags: comparisons, redundancy

Consider this sentence: "Like drinking water, bleeding blood is normal." The phrase "bleeding blood" is clearly redundant, but were I to exclude "blood," I would ruin the gerund+noun structure I established in the first part of the sentence ("drinking water.") Is it better to keep the redundancy for the sake of consistency throughout the sentence, or should I sacrifice that consistency to avoid that redundancy? OR is there simply a better way to write the sentence?

Comment: May I ask what is this for, to establish context? If it were for a poem I would say the alliteration and the redundancy are actually quite wonderful.

Comment: There's always 'shedding blood'.

Comment: The compound noun 'drinking water' complicates here. How does one decide on how _drinking water_ is meant to be understood? _Like drinking water, bottled beer is expensive here_ or _Like drinking water, eating bread was once associated with prison fare_? And 'bleeding blood' for 'blood being spilled' is unidiomatic (and for just 'blood' is outlandish).

Comment: The "normal" parallel construction to go with ***drinking water*** is probably ***passing urine***. Most of us are happy to do both those things many times every day, but few of us would relish the prospect of ***bleeding blood*** (even if it *were* idiomatic to include that second word, which it's not).

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you should never sacrifice form as a price for expression; expression that rests on dubious forms carries the mark of meretricious creation. In the case of your sentence the effect of disregarding the redundancy would create in the reader's mind an impression of incertitude between  equally objectionable possibilities: the first being the suspicion of forced meaning as justified in the apparent parallelism of the forms, the second, from the doubt raised by the inhabitual form (inbuilt redundancy), being that there might be some new concept hidden behind this construction. The overall impression is that of something not very neat. I believe that this is to be avoided.
In such cases all that one may do is look for alternative (solid) forms that will fit the idea. In the case of your sentence, I'd consider for instance the following alternative.

- Like water for drinking, blood from bleeding is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should keep the redundancy or not depends quite strongly on the context of your comparison.  In scientific texts, for example, the rule is never to sacrifice clarity for elegance; in that field, you might improve the sound of the sentence slightly by rearranging it, but you should not shirk from the repetition:

> As it is normal to drink water, it is normal to bleed blood.

Elsewhere your decision could be more subtle:  @Tom O'Bedlam mentions poetry in a comment, and there you can use the alliteration for added effect.

> Like drinking water, bleeding blood is normal,
>
> the only beasts who don't have veins awash with formol,
>
> [...].

Ultimately, the decision of which version of the sentence to use should rest on the following criterion: does it imply what you mean to imply?  The answer by @LPH discusses this somewhat.

Think, also, carefully about why you have this analogy.  Sure, the parallelism of gerund+noun is satisfying, but what is the purpose of the comparison?  When trying to rewrite the sentence to see if I could improve it, I came across a stumbling block; I had written

> Blood is to bleeding exactly as water is to drinking.

but I'd argue that, actually, it is *not* exactly as water is to drinking:  I've heard of plenty of drinks which aren't water, but never of any ‘bleeds’ which aren't blood.  (Some people might even *define* blood as “that which is bled”!)  So why do you need to specify that it is normal to bleed blood?  Are you about to introduce the possibility of bleeding something else?

I think it would be helpful, for the sake of receiving a better answer to your question, to clarify the context/field you are writing this in, as well as the reason for which you need to specify it.  In the mean-time, I hope this helps!